# SQL Server DR options / Transaction log

Tags: sql-server

I have a database about 10 gigs in size on the MDF file in a dev environment.  The log file is out of control and sometimes I run this code just to keep the space down every day.

```
 DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(FIX, TRUNCATEONLY);
 DBCC SHRINKFILE(FIX, 100);
```

It's time to move this into a "production" environment.  Due to space we'll need to keep these logs small.

I have two prod servers and one dev server.  Without knowing anything, I was thinking it would be best to have synchronous database mirroring on the prod1 to prod2, and no clue how to update the database on dev.

We use a lot of SQL CLR, we make schema changes almost daily. I'm sure you've seen a scenario where you put on the whiteboard "lets use prod1 and prod2 and we'll develop on dev and rollout changes" but eventually prod1 ends up as dev and no one uses the other two!

So my questions...

Three servers, one small team.  Prod1, Prod2, and dev.  What's the best DR strategy?

What procedures / processes should be in place to do a good job at keeping sanity, great data quality, yet not sacrifice agility?

Any links on this subject would be very helpful.

Thanks!

***********  UPDATED  ***********

Thank you for your responses!  Great questions….

I should add this for clarity.  I have an Access front end, it runs as a Remote App in the datacenter, the front end connects using an ODBC data source.  3-4 users in the east coast office and west coast office use this front end and update the database several times per hour.  We’re not too high tech but the data is important.

We are using the Enterprise version.  Latency is not a big concern.  The datacenters are east coast / west coast.   I’m not sure how long it would slow things up to update a row in the database if we were using a synchronous strategy.  Half a second is fine.  10 seconds is not fine.  I’m using the FULL model.  Sorry I made a typo, I use the code above in other databases, but have NOT shrunk the logs so far in this one.  Never done a log backup.  I was thinking before “doing something” I should know “what the plan is” so that’s why I’m here to ask the questions on the options.

The data is not such that we need a load balancer, there’s pretty much no load on it.  The main issue and highest priority is data integrity.  Our system has a primary datacenter which has never gone down.  It never will!  (kidding)

In the event of a datacenter / server outage, I just want to be assured of the following:

•   I will manually update an OBDC data source to point to the backup.  Then the front end will work against the other database as the new “prod”.   I’ll handle the users who have issues over the phone.  In fact, they probably wont even bother calling they will just try again later.

•   This needs to work until I figure out what went wrong and then point it back to the first one after its back up and running and all in sync again.

•   As a side note, the biggest reason there would be an “outage” is if there an issue on the VM.

1. How much data can I afford to loose (in terms of time)? 
   If it crashes in the middle of a write its not a big deal.  I can clean it up manually.
2. How much data is changing and at what rate? 
   Changes happen several times per hour by 3-4 users.  But I have huge audit tables so we can tell who changed what at what time.  This is where 90% of the storage comes from in the tables and the log is just annoying.  I can manually get the data right with the tables and no log.
3. How much down time can I afford if a restore is needed? 
   Several hours.  If there is a true datacenter outage this system is not what everyone will be worried about.
4. How difficult is it to reproduce data if it is lost due to not backing up? 
   I can recover it manually, but not looking forward to it!
5. How much can I afford to spend to meet these requirements?
   Zip.  Just my time.

In general, as “proof” we’ve done it right I’d like to run the following test:

•   Pause the VM running prod1

•   Point the ODCB data sources to prod2

•   Make a couple changes in prod 2

•   Unpause the VM, resync the 2 databases

•   Point the ODBC data sources back to prod 1.

If I can do this I feel like I’ve passed the requirements with flying colors.

Thanks!

Comment: Too many unanswered questions.  What version of SQL Server, an what SKU (enterprise, standard, etc.)?  If you want prod1 and prod2 to be in sync, what is your latency requirements?  Between prod and dev, what is latency requirement?  Regarding log file growth, you didn't specify what recovery model, schedule of data and log db backup.  Please add that.

Comment: TIL DR="Disaster Recovery" (I would have guessed Data Replication.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several DR strategies.  Some that deal with HA ( High Availability ) and others that deal with strict DR.  A backup nightly and log backup hourly is a pretty decent DR strategy depending upon how often your data changes.

Here are some good links

[SQL AlwaysOn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saponsqlserver/archive/2012/02/07/sql-server-2012-alwayson-what-is-it.aspx)

[SQL Transactional Replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151706(v=sql.105).aspx)

As far as what to do about your different environments.  Well if I had 2 prod boxes.  I would probably put them both behind a load balancer.  Depending on their function; if they were more or less read only databases then perhaps the Transactional Replication.  If they were doing lots of writes, well then I would make sure we had some sort of session sticky capability combined with AlwaysOn to keep both systems in sync.

To deploy your databases from your "Dev" environment, I would make sure that procs and schema changes prior to deployment created some sort of change script.  Using an ORM like Entity Framework or nHibernate would give you the ability to do that through database migrations.  If you are in an environment that doesn't utilize tools like those then maybe something from Redgate would work like: [DLM Automation Suite](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dlm/dlm-automation-suite/)

Answer (score 3):

If the log file in "out of control" it's most commonly due to having the database in full or bulk logged recovery mode without doing regular log backups.  Part of the log backup process is to truncate the logs.  How often do you do log backups?  IF you aren't doing log backups you should either consider doing them or change your database to simple recovery model.

On a development environment, log backups probably aren't a big concern, but in production you should have a backup strategy that allows proper recovery of data.  Exactly what the "best" DR strategy is depends on your environment and application.  Primarily you need to answer the questions:
1. How much data can I afford to loose (in terms of time)?
2. How much data is changing and at what rate?
3. How much down time can I afford if a restore is needed?
4. How difficult is it to reproduce data if it is lost due to not backing up?
5. How much can I afford to spend to meet these requirements?

Based on your answers you can develop a backup strategy that will meet your needs.  It does no good to do nightly backups without log backups if the answer to question 1 is close to zero and if your data is impossible to reproduce.  On the other hand, a database with easily re-creatable data may be a good candidate for simple recovery model with nightly backups.

BTW, mirroring is not a substitute for backups, it solves a different problem.  If you have someone accidentally drop a table, mirroring will happily mirror the drop to the standby server.  Mirroring protects against many hardware failures, but not operational or user errors.   You'd better still have backups in place.

Comment: A good overview of log file management is here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/64582/

Comment: Thanks for the updates with more info....       "Never done a log backup."    This is the reason your log files are "out of control" when in the full model, the log files don't get truncated until a log backup is done.  And if you've NEVER done a log backup, the full model provides you with no benefit since the most you can recover is your last full backup.  With full recovery model and regular log backups, you can recover to a specific point in time.  PLEASE read the link on SQL Server Central.  It was written by someone who lives and breaths SQL Server and he know the beast pretty well.

Comment: "If I can do this I feel like I’ve passed the requirements with flying colors."  That's really only PART of the requirements.  That would test your FAILOVER setup, but not your RECOVERY strategy.  These are 2 different things.  Failover protects against unexpected server events (crashes, power fails), but does nothing to safeguard your DATA.  You still need a backup and restore strategy as well. There are hundreds of companies that have gone bankrupt for not understanding the difference.

Comment: You really need to look at Mirroring or AlwaysOn.  Imagine you have one server on east coast and one on west coast.  East goes down and the Mirror automatically switches to the West.  Your connection string that targets the databases would have both listed in the connection string and your app would automatically switch over to the one that is up.  When East comes back up it is the secondary and it starts syncing and stays as such unless you manually fail over the primary.  All of this with a good backup strategy and you get your weekends back.